# Непонятная ошибка при печати из JasperReport

Tags: java, jasperreports

Печатаю в консольном приложении через JasperReport-6 несколько тысяч заданий в день на разные сетевые принтеры. Периодически вылетает ошибка:

```
Ошибка:No suitable print service found.
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter.exportReport(JRPrintServiceExporter.java:323)
```

При повторной отправке задания все отлично. Отловить отладчиком не могу. Этих ошибок в день около 100, а заданий несколько тысяч. Печатаю вот так:

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fn), parameters, cn);
if (!jasperPrint.getPages().isEmpty()) {
   PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
   printRequestAttributeSet.add(new JobName("Picklist_ID" + picklistId + "", null));
    if (ps != null) {
        System.out.println("PICKLIST_ID:" + picklistId + " WID:" + workshopId + " MS:" + ms + " " + curWorkMode.toString() + " PRINTER:" + ps.getName() + " " + new Date().toString() + " Prior" + priority);
        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration conf = new SimplePrintServiceExporterConfiguration();
        conf.setPrintRequestAttributeSet(printRequestAttributeSet);
        conf.setPrintServiceAttributeSet(ps.getAttributes());
        conf.setDisplayPageDialog(Boolean.FALSE);
        conf.setDisplayPrintDialog(Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setConfiguration(conf);
        exporter.exportReport();
}}
```

Ошибка вылетает на последней строчке:

exporter.exportReport();

Comment: А на самих принтерах не смотрели? Буфер у них не переполняется? Одно дело - печать 100 страничного документа, другое - печать 100 одностраничных докментов

Comment: Нет принтеры огромные скорость печати около 50 страниц/этикеток в минуту. Повторный запуск программы через несколько секунд отправляет все эти задания на печать правильно и без проблем. В среднем очередь печати на принтерах редко превышает 100 заданий на принтер. Программа запускается раз в 2-3 минуты формирует задания на разные принтеры, а принтеры за этот интервал как правило успевают разобраться с заданиями. Ошибка же как правило не привязано ко времени и может вылетать и в случаях затишья, когда на печать отправляется всего 1 или 2 задания

Comment: А имена принтеров известны? Я бы попробовал вручную добавить, может доп информация если что всплывет
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Epson Stylus 820 ESC/P 2", null));
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("hp LaserJet 1320 PCL 6", null));
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("PDFCreator", null));

Comment: Да принтеры добавляются в цикле по всем принтерам доступным на компьютере. Доступны как имена принтеров, так и экземпляры PrintService

Comment: `PrintService psDefault = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
            PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            System.out.println("Looking for printers:");
            for (PrintService service : services) { ... }`

Comment: А в журналах ОС никаких следов?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35897/discussion-between-alexfess-and-user3195373).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы попробовал вручную добавить, может доп информация если что всплывет `printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("Epson Stylus 820 ESC/P 2", null)); 
printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("hp LaserJet 1320 PCL 6", null)); printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("PDFCreator", null));`